# Program crashing when trying to free()

Tags: c, gdb

Trying to create a program that loops connecting two strings together printing out the alphabet. When i gets to equal 11, I get an error when trying to free(new).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    char* word = NULL;


    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {       
        int buff = 'a' + i;

        // creates first string
        if (i == 0)
        {
            char* new = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);
            if (new == NULL)
            {
                printf("malloc failed");
                return 1;
            }
            sprintf(new, "%c", buff);
            word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new));
            if (word == NULL)
            {
                printf("malloc failed");
                return 1;
            }
            *word = *new;
            free(new);
        }
        // adds string word to string new
        else
        {
            char* new = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);
            if (new == NULL)
            {
                printf("malloc failed");
                return 1;
            }
            sprintf(new, "%c", buff);
            char* new_word = malloc(strlen(word) + strlen(new) + 1);
            if (new_word == NULL)
            {
                printf("malloc failed");
                return 1;
            }
            // Copies combines word and new into new_word
            strcpy(new_word, word);
            strcat(new_word, new);

            // Resizes memory for word and prints new_word into word
            word = (char *) realloc(word, strlen(new_word));
            sprintf(word, "%s", new_word);
            // Frees looped vars
            free(new);
            free(new_word);
        }

        printf("%s\n", word);
    }
}
```

This is the results I get:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdefg
abcdefgh
abcdefghi
abcdefghij
abcdefghijk
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid pointer: 0x08cac028 ***
```

this is what I get from GDB when trying to debug:

```
(gdb) 
56              free(new);
(gdb) info locals
new = 0x804b008 "l"
new_word = 0x804b038 "abcdefghijkl"
buff = 108
i = 11
word = 0x804b018 "abcdefghijkl"
(gdb) n
*** Error in `/home/jharvard/Dropbox/pset6/test': invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x0804b008 ***

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x4408e098 in malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x441d4420 <main_arena>)
    at malloc.c:4093
4093              unlink(av, nextchunk, bck, fwd);
```

Comment: Looks like heap corruption.

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary to dynamically allocate and free one character in each loop iteration. It looks like a huge waste of time.

Comment: Are you using C++? C doesn't allow for loop initial declarations.

Comment: This whole program looks overly complicated.

Comment: @Shashwat, if you're talking about `for(int i = 0; `, that has been allowed in C for the last 15 years

Comment: What is the expected output of this program ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Then you should just check for gcc 4.6.3. If you want, then I will upload screenshot just taken by me.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. gcc defaults to using 25-year-old mode, for reasons best known to its development team; you have to put in the switch "-std=c99" to get 15-year-old mode.

Answer (score 3):

`char* new = malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates a buffer of length 1.
Then you sprintf a char (%c) to that buffer and that takes 2 bytes (the char and the terminating zero) hence a buffer overflow and memory corruption.

BTW allocating very small buffers if totally inefficient and basically useless. You should probably rethink your program from the ground up.

Comment: Also, `word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new));` : `sizeof new` is the size of `char *`. This has nothing to do with how many characters are in the string being pointed to.

Comment: Also, `new_word = malloc(strlen(word) + strlen(new));` doesn't account for the required trailing NULL. Same issue with the `realloc()` later on. The OP's code is basically a mess.

Comment: Yeah I added the + 1 to the mallocs and still getting the same results. sorry if the code is a mess, I am very new to this...

Comment: @user3466332: what dou you expect that program to print?  Please update your question.

Comment: It's not like allocated memories have terminating zeroes anyway... Terminating zero-byte is only there as a convention for end-of-string recognition that is being widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C must always have a null terminator (aka '\0') at the end.  The null terminator marks the end of the string.  Without the null terminator, many of the C string library functions will run past the end of the string, causing a crash if you're lucky.  If you're unlucky, running past the end of a string will corrupt data unrelated to the string, causing bugs that are excruciatingly difficult to find.  The `strlen` function counts the number of characters in a string, but that count **does not** include the null terminator.

```
char *new = malloc(sizeof(char));                      // returns a pointer to 1 byte of memory.
sprintf(new, "%c", buff);                              // writes two characters into that memory, whatever buff is, and a null terminator '\0'
*word = *new;                                          // copies the first character of 'new' into 'word', but doesn't null terminate 'word'
word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new));                   // since new is a pointer, sizeof(new) is the size of a pointer, 4 bytes on 32-bit systems, 8 bytes on 64-bit systems
char* new_word = malloc(strlen(word) + strlen(new));   // allocates enough space for the two string but doesn't include space for the null terminator
word = (char *) realloc(word, strlen(new_word));       // again no space for the null terminator
```

There might be more, but you get the idea.